# Reading error results from mongod in java after insert attempt

Tags: java, mongodb, atomic

I am getting started with mongodb and I would like to do an operation where I attempt to insert a user with a `username`, `password`, and `email`. I have built unique indexes on `username` and `email` so the insert will fail if the specified username or email already exists.

So now I would like to report to the user that either, their email is already registered, or that the username the chose is taken. So I have gotten as far as:

```
CommandResult result = db.getLastError();
```

However, I dont see an easy way to read the error other than parsing through the single error message that it is giving me.

```
{ "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , 
  "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: mojulo.users.$username_1  dup key: { : \"blahblah\" }" ,
  "code" : 11000 , 
  "n" : 0 , 
  "connectionId" : 12 , 
  "ok" : 1.0}
```

Also it appears that this is only reporting the first error that it encounters, is there anyway to do the check for both email and username in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a check for both, then you will have to issue a query yourself to check for it. If you just insert documents, then it will report the first violation of a unique index only. The code `E11000` should only indicate a duplicate key error which should make it easy to spot that it happens. You will need to parse the error message to figure out the collection though.